# How does a package knows to which VLAN to go

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I'm kind new with VLANs concept and I have doubts on how things work and how to configure the ports.

Let's say I have a normal LAN 192.168.1.0 behind SwitchA, VLAN2 192.168.2.0 and VLAN3 192.168.3.0 both behind SwitchB.

192.168.1.1 it's the GW to the internet.
SwitchA and SwitchB are connected through a Trunk.

Whenever a device from the LAN wants to comunicate with either VLAN2 or VLAN3, as for an SSH/RDP to a device or HTTP request, how does it know to which VLAN to go?
There will be a simple routing through the GW using the IPs of the LAN/VLANs? or something more has to be added in terms of tagging?
Because from my understanding I should configure the ports where the devices part VLAN2 are connected, to accept only packages with VID2 and the VLAN3 one with VID3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

Ask yourself: "If I add two Ethernet ports to a host, how will it know which port to use?"

The answer is the same for VLANs.

---

Long answer:

> Whenever a device from the LAN wants to comunicate with either VLAN2 or VLAN3, as for an SSH/RDP to a device or HTTP request, how does it know to which VLAN to go?

In practice, your device usually doesn't care about VLANs – it just sends the packet to the gateway.

The gateway (i.e. the router) makes this decision the same way as it would decide between physical connections: based on subnets and routing tables. Most systems will show VLANs as virtual network interfaces: if the physical Ethernet port is named `eth0`, then VLAN 3 would be `eth0.3` or `eth0_vlan3`. They can have IP addresses assigned, routes added, firewall enabled, and so on.

It is quite rare for hosts to tag their own traffic, and allowing this practically destroys any separation you might have wanted to achieve. But if you *do* configure multiple VLANs (Linux/BSD are capable of this,), then it would make the tagging decision *exactly* the same way as a router: it would see each configured VLAN as a virtual Ethernet port, with its own subnet and routes.

---

(Of course, the switch port going towards the router needs to be configured to carry all VLANs – in some switch models you might need to select "trunk" or "mixed" mode, in other types add the needed VLANs as "tagged".)

Comment: I will repeat what you just said in my own words, just to see if I've actually got it.
given the fact that is not a scenario with only Linux OS, then we can agree that the tagging is done on the router. 
So basically the router has many VLAN interfaces configured such as 192.168.3.X, 192.168.2.x and according to which one it use to communicate with the respective VLAN network, it will tag it with the correct TAG, and sent it through the trunk to the other switch.
The VLAN capable switch will receive the package and determinate to which Port send the tagged package

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: And in the same way, let's say I have a layer 3 switch (VLAN10) to which VLAN2 and VLAN3 are part of, I can also have the Router to just send a general VLAN10 to the L3 switch, and given the destination network of the incoming package (to which VLAN), the L3 switch will add a TAG ID to it and will send to the correct port/VLAN the package which it just received?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you configure. VLANs are tied to the second layer of the ISO/OSI model. At that point you're looking at link based connections. Assuming you use [IEEE 802.1Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q) to implement VLANs there is a specific header added on that layer to allow VLANs.

If you want to allow communication between VLANs you will have to have a device that is accessible from both VLANs and in most cases is going to be a router.

Comment: Yes I know I need a router. What I'm asking is, let's say a PC-A which is not in any VLAN, just a normal LAN, wants to SSH to a PC-B in VLAN2. How does the PC-A knows in which VLAN the PC-B is? Does it has to know at all in order to add a VLAN ID Tag to the package?

Comment: No. That would be what the router needs to do. If you do have an untagged and tagged port on the same switch and both endpoints are trying to communicate with each other I'm not entirely sure what would happen. It does look like it would be configuration/model depended going by [What do switches do to tagged and untagged VLAN packets?](https://serverfault.com/questions/571110/what-do-switches-do-to-tagged-and-untagged-vlan-packets).

Comment: The device that moves packets between VLANs will *always* be a router, even if that's a router built into a layer 3 switch.

Comment: Twisty is absolutely correct. The end devices are usually VLAN un-aware. They only send traffic out of the local subnet based off the default-gateway (layer-3 device). The router / L3-switch will make the forwarding decision based on the current routes available in the routing table.